# In Sonar after execution it showing final memory:8m/453m what is it?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

After running sonar annalyzer, under successfully execution message its showing final memory 8m/453m what does it mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard Maven stuff, see http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Final-Memory-tp114897p114902.html

> First number is the actual memory used within the heap, second number is the total heap size allocated to Java.

Comment: The Maven link you've provided doesn't work anymore